# Discord selfbot - answering on messages from everyone

Tags: node.js, discord

I have Discord selfbot in node.js and I wanna make a bot answering to massages from other server members, for example, if someone type "hey" selfbot will send into DMs "I'm busy rn, sorry"

I have this code but it is not working, I did not get any error but it is not working :(

```
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith('hey'))
    target.send('im afk')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith('idk'))
    message.channel.send("Im Afk");
})
```

The message has to start with 'idk' so that this is triggered.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried say "idk" as well and still norhing

Answer (score 0):

```
client.on('message', message => {
    console.log('Message received: ' + message.content);
    if(message.content === 'hey') {
        message.author.send("Im busy rn, sorry!");
    }
});
```

Try outputting the console output to double check that the message content is actually received properly. Also try using message.content === '' (however this will only work if the whole message content is 'hey')

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do that

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    if(message.content.startsWith('')) {
        message.channel.send("im AFK");
    }
});
```